# Not able to fetch XML tag using Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm having a XML String and where I'm iterating the XML to fetch XML tag values. However for errorDescription tags, its not fetching the values. Here is my code

```
    String arrayOfErrorContext = "<root><item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item>" +
            "<item><errorCode>2</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item></root>";
    def errorCode = "";
    def errorDescription = ""
    String errorMsg = "";
    if(arrayOfErrorContext!= null && !arrayOfErrorContext.isEmpty()) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try
        {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( arrayOfErrorContext ) ) );
            NodeList nList1 = document.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < nList1.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nList1.item(i);
                NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("errorCode");
                Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
                errorCode = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent()
                NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("errorDescription");
                line = (Element) title.item(0);
                errorDescription = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                println errorCode + ":" + errorDescription
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

If any one has better solution in fetching the xml tag value, plz post them

Comment: I have not read through your code, but the `errorDescription` tags look empty, so what values do you actually expect?

Comment: @Roger Gustavsson Exactly. It says Cannot invoke method getTextContent() on null object. But however I don't want this exception to be thrown. It should atleast give emtpy values

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the return value of `line.getFirstChild()` before you try to use it. It will apparently return `null` if the tag is empty. In that case you set `errorDescription` to the empty string (`""`). This check should be done for all tags you retrieve in this manner.

Change

```
errorDescription = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
```

to this

```
if (line.getFirstChild() == null)
    errorDescription = "";
else
    errorDescription = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
```

Comment: Solved. Please check how I changed errorCode = line?.firstChild?.textContent?:""

Comment: Check what where exactly? You should do the same change for `errorCode` if there's a chance it could be empty. The only difference is that the result is saved in another variable.

Comment: I understood Roger. I made in a single statement rather than adding condition as I'm using groovy

Comment: Ah. Ok. I understand.

Comment: Thanks for your update Roger. Can I have your email if you don't mind so that I can reach out to you immediately.

Comment: I actually think I would mind. I think the best thing you can do when you're having a problem is to post a question here on SO (or any other suitable SE site). More people can answer and the question/answer will be saved for future reference for others. If you reach out only to me it may take time before I'm able to respond, even if I know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, but notice that the text is read from a file:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

try {

String arrayOfErrorContext = "<root><item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item>" +
                "<item><errorCode>2</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item></root>";    
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(arrayOfErrorContext)));      
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

System.out.println("----------------------------");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);                              
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("errorCode : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("errorCode").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("errorDescription : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("errorDescription").item(0).getTextContent());

    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

And the output:

### Root element :root

errorCode : 1
errorDescription : 
errorCode : 2
errorDescription :

Comment: Thanks Sandu. But thats not solving. I dont have any external XML file. Please use the string and test

Comment: Looks like a copy paste answer. Why use a file otherwise when OP isn't using one!

Comment: I've edited the code above and it works just fine for me. Maybe that is the answer you are looking for. Check it.

Comment: I'm getting the issue here .. if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

Answer (score 0):

I always parse xml using dom4j, and I solve your question using dom4j too.
`public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException {
        String xml = "<root><item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item>"+"<item><errorCode>2</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item></root>";
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = reader.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Element> list = doc.selectNodes("/root/item");
            for(Element el : list){
                Element errorCode = (Element) el.selectNodes("errorCode").get(0);
                Element errorDescription = (Element) el.selectNodes("errorDescription").get(0);
                System.out.println(errorCode.getText() + " : " + errorDescription.getText());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`

Comment: Sorry. Its not working. Please find the log Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@779cbd8d [Document: name n

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException {
    String xml = "<root><item><errorCode>1</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item>"+"<item><errorCode>2</errorCode><errorDescription></errorDescription></item></root>";
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = reader.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Element> list = doc.selectNodes("/root/item");
        for(Element el : list){
            Element errorCode = (Element) el.selectNodes("errorCode").get(0);
            Element errorDescription = (Element) el.selectNodes("errorDescription").get(0);
            System.out.println(errorCode.getText() + " : " + errorDescription.getText());
        }
    }catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working Jason...Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@1dc0fec [Document: name nul